# Why am I getting multiple lines while plotting distributions?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, statistics, distribution

I have data for to which I am trying to fit a normal and lognormal distribution. `df.head(10)`

```
year    Q
1885     7241
1886     9164
1887     7407
1888     6870
1889     9855
1890    11887
1891     8827
1892     7546
1893     8498
1894    16757
Name: Q, dtype: int64
```

## Fitting distribution

```
from scipy import stats
mean = df['Q'].mean()
std = df['Q'].std()
print(mean, std)
6636.172413793103 3130.779541854595

#Fitting
distnormal = stats.norm.pdf(df['Q'], loc = mean, scale = std)
distlognormal = stats.pearson3.pdf(df['Q'], skew = 1, loc = mean, scale = std)

# Plotting
df.hist(bins=10, edgecolor='#4aaaaa', density = True)
plt.plot(df['Q'], distnormal, color = 'red')
plt.plot(df['Q'], distlognormal, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

But I am getting a plot like this with too many lines. How can I fit a distribution properly?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `df['Q']` as the `x` argument to `plt.plot`. As you data snippet shows, the values in `df['Q']` are not sorted - that's the cause of the issue. Try sorting the data frame by `Q` column prior to plotting with it.

Comment: Ah. So simple. Thanks!